# Why does the use of infinitesimals in deriving the Lie Algebra of some Lie group work?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'd like to know why the following "dirty" derivation of the lie algebra of a lie group works. Take for example the group $SU(2) = \{U \in \mathbb{C_{2\times2}} | UU^\dagger = 1, \text{det}(U) = 1\}$

The arguement goes something like the following, we consider $U = 1 + \epsilon H$ where $\epsilon$ is some "small" or infinitesimal number and $H$ is some 2x2 complex matrix. Then we simple plug in this expression for $U$ into the constraint for $SU(2)$ and we get
$$
(1 + i\epsilon H)(1 + i\epsilon H)^\dagger = 1 \\
$$
to first order this becomes $1 + i\epsilon H - i \epsilon H^\dagger = 1 \implies H = H^\dagger$

There are a world of problems with this derivation from a rigorous standpoint, for example addition is not defined within the group so its not even clear what $1 + i\epsilon H$ even means (or why it should preserve the group structure). Moreover the lie algebra is constructed in a very geometric manner which has to do with left invariant vector fields on the group manifold and so on... and yet I see this kind of derivation where we "differentiate" or "linear approximate" some expression like $U + \epsilon H$ work all the time.

We can think of the tangent space at a point intuitively as the space of linear approximations at that point, but this does not justify why this procedure works so well. What's going on here?

Comment: You can see most of classical Lie groups as preimages of smooth functions. Then their tangent space is the kernel of the differential of such map. In this case you should consider the determinant map $\mathrm{U}_2\to \mathbb{C}$. If you work out the details, you realize that this 'infinitesimal' procedure is just a clumsy way to compute such differential

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent definition of the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$ is the tangent space to the identity element of $G$. For matrix Lie groups, this would be the tangent space to the identity matrix $1$. Elements of $T_1G$ are tangent vectors $v$ to curves $\gamma(t)$ in $G$ such that $\gamma(0) = 1$ and $\dot\gamma(0) = v$. Matrix groups naturally embed into Euclidean space (some $\mathbb R^N$ or $\mathbb C^{N'}$), and it's a theorem of smooth manifold theory that any choice of embedding gives the same tangent space. By embedding $G$ into some Euclidean space, for any vector $v$ in that Euclidean space, there is a curve we can write of the form $\gamma(t) = 1 + tv$, using the vector space structure of the Euclidean space.

However, the curve as written may not lie tangent to the matrix group $G$—it's just jutting out into the large ambient Euclidean space we are embedded in. So to ensure that the curve we wrote will give us a tangent to $G$ at $1$, we ask that $\gamma(t)$ satisfy some constraint so that it lies in $G$ for all $t$ sufficiently small, at least to first-order, since the first-order information of $\gamma(t)$ at $t=0$ is all that we are trying to capture in the notion of "tangent vector." In the example you gave, we should ask that $\gamma(t)\gamma(t)^\dagger = 1$ to first-order at $t = 0$.